# write.table/ adding date automatically

Tags: r, date, write.table

I am using the write.table function.

```
    #code
    write.table(file, file="MY NAME", col.names=T, row.names=FALSE);
```

I also want to add the date automatically each time, thus each file will have the same name an only vary by date? I have tried #Sys.time(); but this isnt working. Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
write.table(file, file=paste("MY NAME",Sys.Date(),sep = "_"), col.names=T, row.names=FALSE)
```

or something similar.

Comment: Hi joran, I am still new with R, could you explain why the paste function works in this way? I get everything else in the code?

Comment: @user2868454 _Why_ it "works in this way"? First you'll have to explain your question. The only sensible answer I can think of is "because that's it's purpose". Why does a hammer work the way it does?

Comment: The `paste` function creates a character string by joining two strings or variables: here `"MY NAME"` and `Sys.Date()` are joined.  The two strings are connected by whatever you specify within `sep`, here `"_"`.  The `paste0` function uses `sep = ''` automatically, or joins the two strings with nothing separating them.

Answer (score 0):

```
 write.table(dat, file = paste("FILE", Sys.time(), sep="_"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try and give this a shot

```
write.table(data, file=paste0("SomeName", Sys.Date()))
```